# Groovy - remove non unique values in a XML payload

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I am trying to extract just two nodes from the xml payload. But it results in some duplicate values.Is there a way to get unique combination of values or to remove the duplicates value later on.

```
import java.text.*
import groovy.xml.*

def text = '''
<root>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 10</loc>
    <city>ABC</city>
    <points>3</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-11T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-13T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
   <city>ABC</city> 
    <points>4</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-18T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-18T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
    <city>ABC</city>
    <points>4</points>
    <StartDate>2023-02-16T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-18T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
    <city>XYZ</city>
    <points>4</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-16T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-12-18T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
</root>
'''
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( text )
def output = new XmlParser().parseText("<root/>")

xml.results.each { resXml ->
       Node resultsNode = output.appendNode( new QName("results"), [:] )
       resXml.children().findAll { child -> child.name() != "points" && child.name()!= "StartDate" && child.name() != "EndDate" }.each { child ->
          resultsNode.appendNode( new QName(child.name()), [:], child.text() )
       }

       
}
       


println XmlUtil.serialize(output )
```

The above code generated the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    
  <results xmlns="">
        
    <loc>Loc 10</loc>
        
    <city>ABC</city>
      
  </results>
    
  <results xmlns="">
        
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
        
    <city>ABC</city>
        
    <loc_name>Loc Desc 11</loc_name>
      
  </results>
    
  <results xmlns="">
        
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
        
    <city>ABC</city>
      
  </results>
    
  <results xmlns="">
        
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
        
    <city>XYZ</city>
      
  </results>
  
</root>
```

It generates some duplicates. Is there a way to remove or only add unique values to the new payload?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a Set to check for duplicates:

```
import java.text.*
import groovy.xml.*

def text = '''
<root>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 10</loc>
    <city>ABC</city>
    <points>3</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-11T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-13T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
   <city>ABC</city> 
    <points>4</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-18T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-18T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
    <city>ABC</city>
    <points>4</points>
    <StartDate>2023-02-16T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-18T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
    <city>XYZ</city>
    <points>4</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-16T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-12-18T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
</root>
'''
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( text )
def output = new XmlParser().parseText("<root/>")

Set uniques = new HashSet()

xml.results.each { resXml ->
    if( !uniques.add( resXml.loc.text() + '-' + resXml.city.text() ) ) return
    
    Node resultsNode = output.appendNode( new QName("results"), [:] )
    resXml.children().findAll { child -> child.name() in [ 'loc', 'city' ] }.each { child ->
        resultsNode.appendNode( new QName(child.name()), [:], child.text() )
    }
}

XmlUtil.serialize( output )
```

returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    
  <results>
        
    <loc>Loc 10</loc>
        
    <city>ABC</city>
      
  </results>
    
  <results>
        
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
        
    <city>ABC</city>
      
  </results>
    
  <results>
        
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
        
    <city>XYZ</city>
      
  </results>
  
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!Is there a way to add the combination loc and city to set as the combination of both could differ as well?

Comment: you can concat both values -> see the update